# Meaning of as! in Swift 1.2 - Xcode 6.3 beta

Tags: swift

I'm just trying XCode 6.3 beta and Swift 1.2

What is the meaning of the `as!` here?

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == signUpViewId {
            var signUpView = segue.destinationViewController as! SignUpViewController
        }

    }
```

Comment: See this pre-released document: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID388 it's already have explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, that if `segue.destinationViewController` is a `SignUpViewController`, it will cast it to a `SignUpViewController`, otherwise it will produce a runtime error.
But if you would use `as?`, that case if `segue.destinationViewController` is **NOT** a `SignUpViewController`, it would be just nil, without runtime error.

Comment: Also `as!` in Swift 1.2 has the same behavior as "plain" `as` in Swift 1.1